# How can I write a grammar that matches "x by y by z of a"?

Tags: antlr4

I'm designing a low-punctuation language in which I want to support the declaration of arrays using the following syntax:

```
512 by 512 of 255  // a 512x512 array filled with 255
100 of 0 // a 100-element array filled with 0
expr1 by expr2 by expr3 ... by exprN of exprFill
```

These array declarations are just one kind of expression among many.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write the grammar rules. I've simplified my grammar down to the simplest thing that reproduces my trouble:

```
grammar Dimensions;

program
  : expression EOF
  ;

expression
  : expression (BY expression)* OF expression
  | INT
  ;

BY : 'by';
OF : 'of';
INT : [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

When I feed in `10 of 1`, I get the parse I want:

[image: Parse tree of <code>10 of 1</code>]

When I feed in `20 by 10 of 1`, the middle `expression` non-terminal slurps up the `10 of 1`, leaving nothing left to match the rule's `OF expression`:

[image: Parse tree of <code>20 by 10 of 1</code>]

And I get the following warning:

```
line 2:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting 'of'
```

The parse I'd like to see is

```
(program (expression (expression 20) by (expression 10) of (expression 1)) <EOF>)
```

Is there a way I can reformulate my grammar to achieve this? I feel that what I need is right-association across both BY and OF, but I don't know how to express this across two operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some non-intellectual experimentation, I came up with some productions that seem to generate my desired parse:

```
expression
  :<assoc=right> expression (BY expression)+ OF expression
  |<assoc=right> expression OF expression
  | INT
  ;
```

I don't know if there's a way I can express it with just one production.